# What is the fastest way to send files of any size and format?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, hadoop, django-rest-framework

I build web application with Angular 6 frontend, Django 1.11 backend and Hadoop 3.1. I need to send files of any size and format in the fastest possible way. My method in Django looks line shown below. Everything seems to be working fine with small files in different formats. However very often when I try to upload larger files I get the error shown at the bottom. Can you recommend the way of sending files of all formats and sizes in the fastest possible way in python? If you need any additional information just let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
def post(self, request):

    key = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').split()[1]

    user_id = Token.objects.get(key=key).user_id

    user_name = User.objects.get(id=user_id).username

    upload_file(request.FILES['file'], user_name)

    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def upload_file(file, user_name):

        response = requests.put(url + ':9870/webhdfs/v1/user/' + str(user_name) + '/' + str(file) + '?op=CREATE&user.name=myuser&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=false' , data=file, headers={'content-type':'application/octet-stream'})

        return response
```

**ERROR:**

```
django_1  | Internal Server Error: /cloud/
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
django_1  |     chunked=chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
django_1  |     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
django_1  |     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
django_1  |     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
django_1  |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
django_1  |     self.send(chunk)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
django_1  |     self.sock.sendall(data)
django_1  | BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
django_1  | 
django_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1  | 
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
django_1  |     timeout=timeout
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
django_1  |     _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
django_1  |     raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
django_1  |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
django_1  |     chunked=chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
django_1  |     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
django_1  |     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
django_1  |     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
django_1  |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
django_1  |     self.send(chunk)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
django_1  |     self.sock.sendall(data)
django_1  | urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
django_1  | 
django_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1  | 
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
django_1  |     response = get_response(request)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
django_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
django_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
django_1  |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
django_1  |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
django_1  |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
django_1  |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
django_1  |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/code/backend/views.py", line 37, in post
django_1  |     response = upload_file(request.FILES['file'], user_name)
django_1  |   File "/code/backend/hdfs.py", line 8, in upload_file
django_1  |     response = requests.put(url + ':9870/webhdfs/v1/user/' + str(user_name) + '/' + str(file) + '?op=CREATE&user.name=myuser&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=false' , data=file, headers={'content-type':'application/octet-stream'})
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 126, in put
django_1  |     return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
django_1  |     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
django_1  |     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
django_1  |     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 495, in send
django_1  |     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
django_1  | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
django_1  | [20/Sep/2018 18:00:59] "POST /cloud/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17134
django_1  | [20/Sep/2018 18:00:59] "GET /cloud/ HTTP/1.1" 200 591
```

Comment: `Can you recommend the way of sending files of all formats and sizes in the fastest possible way?` --> too broad

Comment: I don't think the problem is broad. The question is poorly framed. The deal here is that the file is too big and the connection breaks before the request completes

Comment: chunk upload may help you

Comment: @PatrickArtner What other information do you need? Perhaps source code from frontend?

Comment: @JPG Can you show an example how it could be done?

Comment: depending on the data, a 7zip pipeline or recoding might be possible to make the actual transfer faster - with added computation on both sides. @thedbogh code would not make it better, the question is imho too broadly put. Lets see what other SO*s have to answer.

Comment: if its big enough eventually a carrier pidgeon becomes faster

Comment: You're essentially rewriting the upload feature of HUE, and that has a 100MB limit, I believe, but it writes files to local disk first before uploading

Comment: @cricket_007 But I need to upload larger files than 100MB, too.

Comment: Sure, but just thinking about streaming that much data over HTTP in one batch probably isn't very feasible without some insanely high timeout value. I suggest you look at alternative Python libraries that actually can work with HDFS rather than using WebHDFS